# Accessibility: better place to place tabindex=-1 to avoid duplicate links?

Tags: html, css, accessibility, tabindex, jaws-screen-reader

This question is about Accessibility.

Here is my code:

```
<a href="https://example.com/url-to-details">
    <img src="https://example.com/item.png" alt="some description">
</a>
<a href="https://example.com/url-to-details">some description</a>
```

It's not perfect, as we know we should avoid Adjacent links go to the same URL (this is what the WAVE accessibility tool says for me on my webpage about this piece of code).
With another words, the problem here is you use th Tab key consequently and still appear on the same link. This is not perfect.

My solution is to set **tabindex="-1"** for one of the links.

So, my questions are:

**1. is it a good idea, or you have a better approach?**

**2. Which code is better from the Accessibility point of view:**

```
<a href="https://example.com/url-to-details" tabindex="-1">
    <img src="https://example.com/item.png" alt="some description">
</a>
<a href="https://example.com/url-to-details">some description</a>
```

or

```
<a href="https://example.com/url-to-details">
    <img src="https://example.com/item.png" alt="some description">
</a>
<a href="https://example.com/url-to-details" tabindex="-1">some description</a>
```

P.S. There is a 3rd approach: to unite two `<a></a><a></a>` into one such as `<a> picture + some description</a>`, but I would avoid it for some reasons.

P.P.S. The description text "some description" is equal for both the image description and the text in the anchor tag.

Comment: The 3rd approach is the only thing that really makes sense here. _“My solution is to set tabindex="-1" for one of the links.”_ - that is not a “solution” to anything here.

Comment: What are the "some reasons" for which you would avoid combining the links? It is the simplest solution.

Comment: `but I would avoid it for some reasons`. What reasons?

Comment: Just use a screenreader and see what it sounds like. Think about the people that will be visiting your site. 

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromevox/kgejglhpjiefppelpmljglcjbhoiplfn?hl=en

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see a use case for having both an image link and an adjacent textual link that use the same URL. It should be a single link, so you have three options:

1. get rid of the image link,
2. get rid of the textual link,
3. combine the image and the text into a **single link**, where the image has an **empty `alt` attribute**:

   `<a href="https://example.com/url-to-details"><img src="https://example.com/item.png" alt=""> some description</a>`

In the third case, the `alt` attribute should be empty in order to avoid duplication of text (screen reader users don't want to hear the link text twice). This also results in simpler code that does not rely on `tabindex="-1"`. See also [WCAG Technique H2: Combining adjacent image and text links for the same resource](https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/WCAG20-TECHS/H2.html).

Note that using two adjacent links, both with the `href` attribute and one of them having `tabindex=-1`, as proposed in the question, will result in both links being listed in a screen reader's list of links. This duplication should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your alt description should be equal to your link text is a misguided approach, in my opinion.

Let's say you are designing a products list page for an online store.

If the link goes to a product detail page, then the link text should describe that detail page. However, the image alt should describe the image itself, not the detail page.

```css
.link {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<a class="link" href="https://www.mywebsite.org/detail-page-100">
  <img class="link-img" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="2 puppies running through a meadow in the summer sun">
  <span class="link-desc">Buy organic pet food - 5kg</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Then the screen reader will hear "*2 puppies running through a meadow in the summer sun, Buy organic pet food - 5kg, link*".  That's a really long link description.  What's the point of the image description of puppies running?  In this case, the image is purely decorative and doesn't provide additional info that is required for screen reader users.  The `alt` can just be "" (quote-quote).

Comment: You could also argue that the image is not purely decorative.

Comment: It’s decorative because it doesn’t add any new information.

Comment: If that's the case, then it should not be there in the first place.

Comment: what a silly comment.  are you saying that all decorative images should be removed from webpages?  really?

Answer (score 1):

The `tabindex` only changes the keyboard order, but screen reader will still announce the same link twice.

Making the `img` clickable using javascript will avoid annoying keyboard users or screenreader users, letting mouse users click on the image itself.

Comment: A `tabindex` attribute with a negative value is intended to take the element out of the tab order. See [Using the tabindex attribute](https://developer.paciellogroup.com/blog/2014/08/using-the-tabindex-attribute/).

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe you seem to assume that the only way to navigate a page is by tabbing.

Comment: @ksav Certainly not. But this is a question about the `tabindex` attribute, which is used to make elements keyboard-accessible. Tabbing is way to navigate through a page, although that may also involve other keys (especially if you are using a screen reader).

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe Moving an element out of the tab order does not prevent some screenreaders from reading it (when listing all links for instance) as long as it has the `link` role.

Answer (score 1):

From a purely [WCAG](https://www.w3.org/WAI/standards-guidelines/wcag/) accessibility point of view, **nothing** has to change in the original code.  That fact that [WAVE](https://wave.webaim.org/help) points it out is just an artifact of that tool.  It's not an error, but an "alert" (in WAVE terms).  The doc for WAVE says this about "alerts":

> The goal should not be to get rid of **all** icons, except for the errors. Alerts will require close scrutiny - the[y] likely represent an *end user issue*.

The key being that alerts are "end user" issues, meaning usability or user experience issues.  Not accessibility failures.

So, if you're trying to comply to WCAG AA, having a redundant link is not a failure and does not have to be fixed.  But if you're looking at the user experience, reducing the number of tab stops and links that point to the same destination is always a good thing.

**How** you fix that issue seems to be the crux of the OP.  When two links that are adjacent point to the same location, the best way is to combine the links into one.  Adding `tabindex="-1"` to one is generally a bad idea because that only affects keyboard users and not screen reader users.

Answer (score 0):

I would keep them both, because if a person using a screen reader is tabbing through your website you would like them to hear the image description as well as the text in the anchor tag.

The correct answer is - it depends.

If your image better describes your link, then use the image.

If your anchor tag better describes it - then use the `<a>`.

Some info for [`tabindex`](http://accessibleculture.org/articles/2010/05/tabindex/)

Please see all the accessibility you can add to a link [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#link)

Comment: Thank you. But, in my question above states the descriptions are equal.  I will add a comment about that to my question to emphasize that.